# How do i run animation two, only after animation one has completed?

Tags: javascript

I understand this question has been answered already, but most of them are in jquery. At the moment function one and function two run at the same time. But how do I alter this code so function two only runs after function one has completed its journey to the top of the screen and back down again?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function start() {
      animation();
      animationone();
    }
    function animation() {
      obj = document.getElementById("jbtext");
      obj.style.position = "absolute";
      obj.style.bottom = "0px";
      w = document.body.clientHeight;
      goUp = true;
      animateText();
    }
    var obj, w, goUp;
    function animateText() {
      var pos = parseInt(obj.style.bottom, 10);
      (goUp) ? pos++ : pos--;
      obj.style.bottom = pos + "px";
      if (pos < 0) {
        goUp = true;
      }
      if (pos > w) {
        goUp = false;
      }
      if (pos < 0) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(animateText, 10);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start, false);
    function animationone() {
      obja = document.getElementById("jbtexta");
      obja.style.position = "absolute";
      obja.style.left = "10px";
      obja.style.bottom = "10px";
      wtwo = document.body.clientWidth;
      goRight = true;
      animatesecond();
    }
    var obja, wtwo, goRight;
    function animatesecond() {
      var position = parseInt(obja.style.left, 10);
      (goRight) ? position++ : position--;
      obja.style.left = position + "px";
      if (position > wtwo) {
        goRight = false;
      }
      if (position < 0) {
        goRight = true;
      }
      if (position < 0) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(animatesecond, 10);
    }
  </script>
  <p id="jbtext"> first function</p>
  <p id="jbtexta"> second function</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises in javascript. Promises are a block of code that will run asynchronously and return at a later point in time. It "returns" by calling the resolve method which is an argument of the Promise constructor. You can then chain promises together to accomplish what you need.

```
function animationOne() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // ... do your logic for the first animation here here.

        resolve(); // <-- call this when your animation is finished.
    })
}

function animationTwo() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // ... do your logic for animation two here.

        resolve(); // <-- call this when your animation is finished.
    })
}

animationOne().then(function() {
    animationTwo();
})
```

Comment: Peter, did you use Javascript only to do that? or is there some jquery in it? I'd like to do it in Javascript only.

Comment: This is all javascript only, supported in all major browsers except IE. It was introduced in ECMAScript 2015

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way of Peter LaBanca's answer.

I do not enjoy using Promises. Instead, I use `async` and `await`

```js
function runFirst() {
  //animation
}
async function waitThenRun() {
  await runFirst();
  //second animation
}
waitThenRun();
```

I just don't enjoy the idea of `Promise`. The code above runs `waitThenRun()`. That function then runs `runFirst()`, but waits until it has been finished to run the rest of the function. Having `setTimeout` or other ways of delaying code in `runFirst` means you should use `Promise`. (Pure JS)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following script AnimationOneAndTwo? The script uses setInterval to “run” the animations. To use it create an instance using the factory method createInstance. Then when the condition or conditions to end the first animation are true call on the next method of the instance to start the second animation. Then when the condition or conditions to end the second animation are true call on the end method of the instance. The following snippet includes the definition for AnimationOneAndTwo and its application to your situation. For more details on how I created the function please refer to “[How to Run One Animation after Another: A Reply to a Question at Stack Overflow](https://www.academia.edu/40852670/How_to_Run_One_Animation_after_Another_A_Reply_to_a_Question_at_Stack_Overflow)”.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
/***
 * AnimationOneAndTwo
 * Copyright 2019 John Frederick Chionglo (jfchionglo@yahoo.ca)
 ***/
function AnimationOneAndTwo(parms) {
  this.id = parms.id;
}
AnimationOneAndTwo.objs = [];
AnimationOneAndTwo.createProcessLogic = function(parms) {
  var obj;
  obj = new AnimationOneAndTwo({id: parms.id});
  AnimationOneAndTwo.objs[parms.id] = obj;
  if ("animationStepOne" in parms) {}
  else {
    throw new RangeError("animationStepOne not found in parms.");
  }
  obj["animationStepOne"] = parms.animationStepOne;
  if ("animationStepTwo" in parms) {}
  else {
    throw new RangeError("animationStepTwo not found in parms.");
  }
  obj["animationStepTwo"] = parms.animationStepTwo;
  if ("speed" in parms) {
    obj.msf_0 = parms.speed;
  }
  return obj;
};
with (AnimationOneAndTwo) {
  prototype.ap = window;
  prototype.dc = window.document;
  prototype.np = 6;
  prototype.nt = 4;
  prototype.ni = 7;
  prototype.no = 3;
  prototype.nn = 1;
  prototype.nr = 1;  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'iE_in_' + ia[j] + ' = function() {\n';
      str +=  '  this.s_in_' + ia[j] + ' = ( this.m_' + pa[j] + ' < 1 ? true : false );\n';
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([1], [0]);
  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'iE_in_' + ia[j] + ' = function() {\n';
      str +=  '  this.s_in_' + ia[j] + ' = ( this.m_' + pa[j] + ' < 1 ? false : true );\n';
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([0,2,3,4,5,6], [0,2,0,2,5,4]);
  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'fE_in_' + ia[j] + ' = function() {\n';
      str +=  '  this.m_' + pa[j] + ' -= 1;\n';
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([3,4,5,6], [0,2,5,4]);
  (function(oa, pa, ka) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<oa.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'fE_ou_' + oa[j] + ' = function() {\n';
      str +=  '  this.m_' + pa[j] + ' += 1;\n';
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([0,1,2], [1,3,2]);
  (function(ta, ia) {
    var str, j, k, h;
    for (j=0; j<ta.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'iE_T_' + ta[j] + ' = function() {\n';
        for (h=0; h<ia[j].length; h++) {
          k = ia[j][h];
          str += '  this.iE_in_' + k + '();\n';
        }
        if (ia[j].length<1) {
          str += '  this.s_t_' + ta[j] + ' = true;\n';
        } else {
          str += '  this.s_t_' + ta[j] + ' = this.s_in_' + ia[j][0];
          for (k=1; k<ia[j].length; k++)
            str += ' && this.s_in_' + ia[j][k];
        }
        str += ';\n';
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([0,1,2,3], [[0], [1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5]]);
  (function(ta, ia, oa) {
    var str, j, k, h;
    for (j=0; j<ta.length; j++) {
      str = '  prototype.' + 'fE_T_' + ta[j] + ' = function() {\n';
        for (h=0; h<ia[j].length; h++) {
          k = ia[j][h];
          str += '  this.fE_in_' + k + '();\n';
        }
        for (h=0; h<oa[j].length; h++) {
          k = oa[j][h];
          str += '  this.fE_ou_' + k + '();\n';
        }
      str += '};\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })([0,1,2,3], [[], [], [3, 6], [4, 5]], [[], [], [2], []]);
  (function(parms) {
    var str, j, k, h, i;
    var ta = parms.ta;
    var pad = parms.pad;
    var pat = parms.pat;
    var tar = parms.tar;
    var tad = parms.tad;
    var tav = parms.tav;
    for (i=0; i<ta.length; i++) {
      j = ta[i];
      str = '  prototype.' + ' pEv_T_' + j + ' = function() {\n';
      str += '    this.fE_T_' + j + '();\n';
      for (h=0; h<tar[j].length; h++) {
        k = tar[j][h];
        str += '    this.iE_T_' + k + '();\n';
      }
      str += '  };\n';
      eval(str);
    }
  })({
     ta: [0,1,2,3],
    tar: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]
  });
  prototype.pEv_T_0 = function() {
    this.fE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.animationStepOne();
  };
  prototype.pEv_T_1 = function() {
    this.fE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
    this.animationStepTwo();
  };
  prototype.ipn = function() {
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
  };
  prototype.im = function() {
    var j, h, pa;
    for (j=0; j<this.np; j++) {
      eval('this.m_' + j + ' = 0');
    }
    pa = [1,2,3];
    for (h=0; h<pa.length; h++) {
      j = pa[h];
      eval('this.m_' + j + ' = ' + 0);
    }
    pa = [0,4,5];
    for (h=0; h<pa.length; h++) {
      j = pa[h];
      eval('this.m_' + j + ' = ' + 1);
    }
  };
  prototype.ai_0 = undefined;
  prototype.msf_0 = 10;
  prototype.mss_0 = 1500;
  prototype.ms_0 =   prototype.msf_0;
  prototype.sp_0 = function() {
    if (this.ai_0) { this.ap.clearInterval(this.ai_0); this.ai_0 = undefined; }
  };
  prototype.st_0 = function() {
    if (this.ai_0) { this.sp_0(); }
    this.ai_0 = this.ap.setInterval('AnimationOneAndTwo.objs[' + this.id + '].rn_0()', this.ms_0);
  };
  prototype.rn_0 = function() {
    var t;
    var et = [];
    if (this.s_t_0) {
        this.pEv_T_0();
    } else if (this.s_t_1) {
        this.pEv_T_1();
    } else {
      if (this.ai_0) {
        this.sp_0();
      }
    }
  };
  prototype.start = function() {
    with (this) {
      if (ai_0) { sp_0(); }
      im();
      ipn();
      st_0();
    }
  };
  prototype.next = function() {
    if (this.s_t_2) {
      this.pEv_T_2();
    } else if (this.s_t_3) {
      this.pEv_T_3();
    }
  };
  prototype.end = function() {
    if (this.s_t_2) {
      this.pEv_T_2();
    }
    if (this.s_t_3) {
      this.pEv_T_3();
    }
  };
}

    var aotobj;
    function start() {
      animation();
      animationone();
      aotobj = AnimationOneAndTwo.createProcessLogic({
        id: 12345
        , animationStepOne: animateText
        , animationStepTwo: animatesecond
      });
      aotobj.start();
    }

    function animation() {
      obj = document.getElementById("jbtext");
      obj.style.position = "absolute";
      obj.style.bottom = "0px";
      w = document.body.clientHeight;
      goUp = true;
//      animateText();
    }
    var obj, w, goUp;
    function animateText() {
      var pos = parseInt(obj.style.bottom, 10);
      (goUp) ? pos++ : pos--;
      obj.style.bottom = pos + "px";
      if (pos < 0) {
        goUp = true;
      }
      if (pos > w) {
        goUp = false;
      }
      if (pos < 0) {
        aotobj.next();
        return;
      }
//      setTimeout(animateText, 10);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start, false);
    function animationone() {
      obja = document.getElementById("jbtexta");
      obja.style.position = "absolute";
      obja.style.left = "10px";
      obja.style.bottom = "10px";
      wtwo = document.body.clientWidth;
      goRight = true;
//      animatesecond();
    }
    var obja, wtwo, goRight;
    function animatesecond() {
      var position = parseInt(obja.style.left, 10);
      (goRight) ? position++ : position--;
      obja.style.left = position + "px";
      if (position > wtwo) {
        goRight = false;
      }
      if (position < 0) {
        goRight = true;
      }
      if (position < 0) {
//        AnimationOneAndTwo.objs[12345].end();
        aotobj.end();
        return;
      }
//      setTimeout(animatesecond, 10);
    }

  </script>
  <p id="jbtext"> first function</p>
  <p id="jbtexta"> second function</p>
</body>
</html>
```